# Как поместить стрелки навигации внутри контейнера с картинкой fancybox?

Tags: css, jquery, fancybox

Есть группа картинок галереи `fancybox` 3 версии.

Как расположить стрелки влево вправо внутри белой секции (а не по краям как сейчас), по аналогии как в предыдущей версии библиотеки [демо](http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/) но, сохранив при этом адаптивность.

Если есть вариант создать белые отступы от картинки так, чтобы при раскрытии картинки не наблюдалось эффекта дергания - будет вообще здорово!

**Код:**

```js
$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
  btnTpl: {

    arrowLeft: '<button data-fancybox-prev class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_left prev" title="{{PREV}}">' +
      '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
      "</button>",

    arrowRight: '<button data-fancybox-next class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_right next" title="{{NEXT}}">' +
      '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
      "</button>"

  }

});
```

```css
.fancybox-container .fancybox-image {
  padding: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.fancybox-container .fancybox-navigation .fancybox-button.prev,
.fancybox-container .fancybox-navigation .fancybox-button.next {
  width: 69px;
  height: 69px;
  font-size: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fe7f40;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.6/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.6/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg"></a>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg"></a>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Решил таким образом:**

```js
$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
  arrows: false,
  afterLoad: function(instance, current) {
    if (instance.group.length > 1 && current.$content) {
      current.$content.append('<button class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_right next" data-fancybox-next><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button data-fancybox-prev class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_left prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.fancybox-container .prev,
.fancybox-container .next {
  width: 69px;
  height: 69px;
  font-size: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fe7f40;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.fancybox-container .next {
  right: 20px;
}

.fancybox-container .prev {
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.6/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.6/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg"></a>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg"></a>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: При открытии картинки во всплывающем окне увеличиваются стрелки навигации, как это исправить??